# How to have Sent items wrap to full width of pane in Thunderbird (plain text)?

Tags: email, imap, thunderbird, gmail-imap

When I view plain text Sent items in Thunderbird, it automatically adds line breaks so they do not wrap to the full width of the viewing pane when displayed.

This makes it awkward if I want to later copy and paste some text from a Sent item into a new plain text e-mail, or word processor because the text won't wrap correctly to accommodate the width of the pasted location.

I'd like to make it so that Sent items will flow to the full width of the screen in Thunderbird, and when pasted to a new location.

I'm using Windows XP Home SP 3, Thunderbird 3.1.11, with a Gmail account using IMAP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found that changing the mailnews.wraplength value from the default of 72 to 10,000 (or "any" large value) provided the behaviour I wanted.

Comment: 0 (zero) seems to be an acceptable value. Tested with Thunderbird 45.1.0 on KDE on PC-BSD 11.0-CURRENTMAY2016. Related: http://superuser.com/questions/378184/tell-thunderbird-not-to-truncate-or-wrap-lines-when-sending-email#comment786914_378238